# AngularJS Show inputted data after submit form

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, forms, bootstrap-modal

I have form with input fields, radio buttons, and select boxes.

How I can show all inputted data on another page or on modal window of this page?

For radio boxes, I want to show text inside `getWord`, but the form has 2 languages.

```
<div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-sm-offset-1">
                                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                                        <label class="radio-inline">
                                            <input type="radio" class="radiobox" name="newpat" ng-model="isNewpat" value="true"><span>{{getWord('New')}}</span></label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                                        <label class="radio-inline">
                                            <input type="radio" class="radiobox" name="existpat" ng-model="isNewpat" value="false"><span>{{getWord('Exist')}}</span></label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

I also want to be able to see the information inputted in input fields and chosen `datepicker`.

For example, I used this, but it did not work:

```
<div class="modalwindow text-center">
             <h1>{{getWord.appoitmentmessage}}</h1>

           <p>{{message}}</p>
          <div>{{user.name}}</div>
          <div>{{user.email}}</div>
        </div>
```

Comment: You are using the same `ng-Model`. for both inputs. i.e `ng-model="isNewpat"`

Comment: when i make 2 another model i can choice 2 radio together.

Comment: No in that case it won't be possible. Actually i'm unable to understand you problem. 

If you use `ng-model="isNewpat"` the value selected on any radio click will be added to `$scope.isNewpat` if that is what you want. Your above code will do the same

Comment: isNewpat: $scope.isNewpat,

Comment: $scope.makeAptmn = function () {
            var apnmt = {
                patient: $scope.patient,
                doctorId: $scope.selectedDctrId,
                isNewpat: $scope.isNewpat,
            };

Comment: what next ? i just see true or false. but me need look what inside span, getword

Comment: Do you want 'New' instead of true ? and 'Exist' instead of false ?

Comment: yes i want see getwort(new)new wneh choiced true, new i have 2 languages

Comment: see the updated example.. I have updated the answer for you. Now the ng-model has same name but i have replaced `getWord.appoitmentmessage`with `isNewpat`. And changed the values from `true/false` to `New/Exist. Let me know if this is what you wanted ?

Answer (score 0):

As much I understand your question. I think this will work for you. If you want to show value of radio-box selection in modal. Please elaborate more so in can help further

**Change this**

```
 <div class="col-sm-4">
        <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" class="radiobox" name="newpat" ng-model="isNewpat" value="New"><span>New</span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
         <label class="radio-inline">
         <input type="radio" class="radiobox" name="existpat" ng-model="isNewpat" value="Exist"><span>Exist</span></label>
    </div>
```

And this Also

```
<div class="modalwindow text-center">
      <h1>{{isNewpat}}</h1>

      <p>{{message}}</p>
      <div>{{user.name}}</div>
      <div>{{user.email}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: when i change names ng-model, now i can choise 2 radio button together.